# How to resolve issue of Persian font showing in Anaconda power shell

Tags: shell, anaconda, farsi

How can I solve the problem of a Persian font showing in Anaconda power shell?

When I want write a code that has Persian (Farsi) font in the Anaconda power shell, the letters are displayed as "?????".

I changed region in Windows and installed Persian fonts (a very different way to try and solve this), but I seems this doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Anaconda is a virtual environment manager. PowerShell is a Windows shell. There is no such thing as "Anaconda power shell". What platform are you using? Linux? Windows? Something else? What terminal are you using? If characters aren't being displayed correctly its usually because your terminal doesn't support those characters. Are you using Unicode or some other character encoding?

Comment: @KurtisRader when installing anaconda on windows, it creates a shortcut it names `Anaconda Powershell Prompt` which is windows powershell, but calls condas startup script to set everything up such that conda commands can be run in that powershell session.

Comment: @FlyingTeller, Okay, good to know, but it doesn't change the fact there is no such thing despite a Windows shortcut with that label. :-)  Furthermore, the O.P. should have been able to tell us whether or not the Farsi characters displayed correctly in a standard Powershell session. Not to mention telling us a lot of other important details such as the platform they are using and the versions of the relevant software. Not to mention that this is the rare case where a screenshot might be justified and useful.

Comment: @esigholam, It is unclear what this has to do with Anaconda. How are you writing those characters to the "Anaconda Powershell" terminal? What happens if you output those Farsi characters in a standard (non-Anaconda) Powershell terminal session?  It shouldn't be necessary to change the Windows region but you should have told us what was  the original region and the region you changed to. Your problem description suggests you are using a Windows Farsi code page rather than Unicode. Forgive me for these questions because I am used to Unix systems where Unicode is the standard for such things.